# Is this song sung in English?

Tags: listening

Recently I was haunted by Tranquil Eye from Cocteau Twins. I couldn't figure out what lyrics the singer sang. Did she sing in English, or are there no lyrics at all? (I couldn't find any on the Internet.)

The music can be listened here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Oa9aV9aqc0.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about song lyrics. Which are clearly "English", but so distorted that no-one has seriously attempted to transcribe them (and obviously the author never wrote them down anywhere that's easily accessible today).

Comment: I think the answer might be "sorta".

Comment: Interesting band. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocteau_Twins):'At times barely decipherable, Fraser seemed to veer into glossolalia and mouth music. Allmusic reviewer Ned Raggett writes that "part of her appeal is how she can make hard-to-interpret lyrics so emotionally gripping."'

Answer (score 2):

A [google search](https://www.google.com/#q=cocteau+twins+tranquil+eye+lyrics&start=10) for *cocteau twins tranquil eye lyrics* returns links to dozens of song-lyrics sites.  All of the lyrics-site links I followed returned “no lyrics for this song” (or equivalent) messages.

More positively, some of the links led to statements about or analyses of lyrics of Cocteau Twins songs ([1](http://www.cocteautwins.org/analysis.htm),[2](http://www.cocteautwins.com/html/dynamine/glossary.html),[3](http://www.cocteautwins.com/html/dynamine/lyrics.html)).  It appears that many of the words in their songs are English, and many are not; and the English words often don't form sentences.   It's easy to hear numerous English words scattered through the [Tranquil Eye](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Oa9aV9aqc0) youtube that you linked to. As another example, the first chorus of [Violaine](http://www.cduniverse.com/cocteau-twins-violaine-lyrics-7611968.htm) is:

> Ik does a dashik dozen
>   Ik does a yield gig does
>   Ik does alone Cheyenne
>   Mad at them who tease him scrawling

which includes a mix of Dutch or German-like words with a good bit of English.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I can only catch some English words here and there such as "help me", "hug me", "love me", and something sounds like "love is 'th'cha, la la love, la la love". As for Violaine, I believe that the lyrics on the web is just plain wrong. Perhaps there is not even one English word in the lyrics, except for the chorus part that seems like rap in English in the background near the end of the song. The first line sounds more like German "ich das ..." to me, but that maybe just my imagination. :)